# Widget is not updating

Tags: swift, xcode, widget

I have an app and a widget that I would like to be updated every day after midnight. The app is updating, but the widget ins't. Tried different approaches with the Timeline, but it is not working. In the simulator it is working fine, but not when I run the app on my phone (via TestFlight). Can one of you help me out!

**Below the code for the widget:**

...

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {

func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
    SimpleEntry(date: Date())
}

func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
    let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    completion(entry)
}

func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) ->    Void) {
     let currentDate = Date()
     let entries = [
         SimpleEntry(date: currentDate)
         ]
     let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
     completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
let date: Date
}

struct AhackadayWidgetEntryView : View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("Your Hack of the Day")
            .font(.footnote)
        Divider()
          .padding(.horizontal)
          .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        
        Spacer()
        Text(mijnPlaatje.mijnKop())
            .font(.headline)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        
        Image(mijnPlaatje.WidgetPicture())
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
            .padding(.horizontal)
        Spacer()
    }
    .widgetURL(URL(string: "myapp://link"))
}
}

@main
struct AhackadayWidget: Widget {
let kind: String = "AhackadayWidget"

var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
    StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
        AhackadayWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
    }
    .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
    .description("This is an example widget.")
}
}

struct AhackadayWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    AhackadayWidgetEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(date: Date()))
        .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
}
}
```

...

**The code in the app itself to call for an update of the timeline below.**

*The app itself does the update every night. So the TimeChangeNotification is working correctie. However, the widget is not updated.*

```
       .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
                    for: UIApplication.significantTimeChangeNotification)) { _ in
                    ContentView.displayDate = Date()
                    curDate = myPict.myPicture()
                    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

Comment: `.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher` will only fire if your app hasn't been backgrounded by the system. That's probably not what you're looking for. Have you looked at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app?

Comment: Thanks jnpdx for your swift reply. However, the app is updated overnight, so the .onReceive is working properly (the contentview is updated). But the widget is not triggered to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
```

you are telling IOS to reload of your widget as soon as possible. Even if no new data is available. As IOS is managing the point in Time when the Widget gets updated it will start to update about every 5 - 15 minutes at the beginning. But it will start to take much more as time passes.

TLDR: You are most probably out of budget for reloads.

Try:

```
let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .never)
```

With this your timeline will only reload when your app wants it to reload.

Make sure your

```
WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
```

gets called.

Reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

Edit:

> In the simulator it is working fine, but not when I run the app on my phone (via TestFlight).

Updates while you are in the debugger do not count against your budget.

Comment: Thanks Burnsi! I am going to give it a try and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Didn’t help. No update of the widget tonight.

Comment: Well, then your problem is somewhere else. Beyond the scope of the code you provided. For example what does 'mijnPlaatje.WidgetPicture()' do? How and from where do you get new data?

Comment: Hi Burnsi, you were right. Have build a new widget and also added tshowing the date and time. The date and time are updated, however the text and picture ins't. Thanks for your advice!